# nodejs mongodb query document for multiple values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

so my question is. Is it possible to query a document for multiple values example

```
            var channelLinked = {'channel 1': '' || 'channel 2': ''}
            db1.collection('proxies').find(channelLinked).toArray(function(err,result){
              console.log(result);
              db.close()
            })
```

i know the above code is invalid but thats the only example i can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) operator

> The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions.

```
 db1.collection('proxies').find({ $or: [ { 'channel 1': 'abc' }, { 'channel 2': 'abc'} ] }).toArray(function(err,result){
          console.log(result);
          db.close()
        })
```

There are multiple [Logical Query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/) available ([$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and),[$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not),[$nor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/#op._S_nor))

Comment: thank you i had figured it out before the post but you are 100% correct